# Delete Dataset in Salesforce Analytics Cloud

Tags: data, analytics-cloud

I have a dataset that is redundant with a newer dataset kept current by integration. The dataset name is a duplicate and causes errors within other functions in the app. I know how to rename the dataset to fix the naming issue but does anyone know how to delete it entirely?

The dataset is also referred to as a DataMart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is available in the Summer 15 release

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_bi_dataset_delete.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can no longer delete a dataset through workbench. At current release, there is no way to delete a dataset

Comment: I'm fairly certain SFDC still has access. I will verify this week.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to delete a dataset via the UI currently. This can only be accomplished using the workbench.

You can completely overwrite the dataset by clicking on edit in be UI and uploading a new data and schema file.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the Dataset from Wave Analytic App UI also. But make sure it is not schedule or running in any Job/DataFlow.And by hard deleting the Dataset, it will delete the reference of it in Lens and Dashboards.